# Fabric TwitterKit Error attempting to like: Request failed: unauthorized (401) iOS

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I am showing tweets using fabric twitterkit iOS.
eg - // TODO: Base this Tweet ID on some data from elsewhere in your app

```
[[[TWTRAPIClient alloc] init] loadTweetWithID:@"732514364792639488" completion:^(TWTRTweet *tweet, NSError *error) {
if (tweet) {

    TWTRTweetView *tweetView = [[TWTRTweetView alloc] initWithTweet:tweet style:TWTRTweetViewStyleRegular];
    tweetView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 286, 518);
    tweetView.showActionButtons = YES;
    tweetView.theme = TWTRTweetViewThemeDark;
    tweetView.delegate = self;


    [self.view addSubview:tweetView];


} else {
    NSLog(@"Tweet load error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

}];
Initially when I tap on like/favorite it takes me to login, once I login it takes me back to my app and the tweet is liked.
Now if I revoke access to my app from my twitter account, I keep on getting this error whenever I tap on like and doesn't ask to authorize/login to the app.
[TwitterKit] Error attempting to like: Request failed: unauthorized (401)
Is there any way to have a call back or notification for this error in my controller? how do I handle this? 
I am using Twitterkit version 2.0.2.

Comment: Not sure if this would help but you could use TWTRComposerViewController from TwitterKit. See docs here - https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/compose-tweets